# Creating ASP.Net DataBound control that renders table with multiple tbodies

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, data-binding

I need to create a data-bound control where each item renders `<tbody><ItemTemplate></tbody>`.  Further, I'd also like to put the `<HeaderTemplate>` in a `<thead>` rather than a `<tbody>` row as the `<asp:DataList>` does.  I need full control of the item template.  It needs to be able to render an editable row, like the `DataList` does.

I believe I need to make a custom control for this (but if not, please let me know--it would save a lot of time).  What's the best parent class to extend?  My guess is that it's either `DataList` or `DataBoundControl`.

Comment: you do not need a custom control for this why you need to do is `GOOGLE DataGridView ItemTemplate` there are plenty of working examples on Stackoverflow as well as on the Internet.. this is what `You need to Create`

Comment: It looks like `DataGrid`s allow you to template each column.  I need to template entire rows.  Each item will render a `tbody` with between 2 and 3 rows, and each row has a different number of columns (`colspan='x'`).  Am I missing something, or does the `DataGrid` not have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what I'm looking for is `<asp:Repeater>` with a little extra code for editing since it doesn't have an `<EditItemTemplate>`.

**.ascx**

```
<asp:Repeater id="rItems" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rItems_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rItems_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>...</thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tbody id="itemRows" runat="server">
            ...
            <asp:Button ... CommandName="Edit" />
            ...
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="editItemRows" runat="server" visible="false">...</tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**.ascx.cs**

```
private int m_editIndex = -1;

protected void rItems_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Edit":
            m_editIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
            break;
        ... // Cancel, Update, Delete, etc
        case "Cancel":
            m_editIndex = -1;
            break;
    }

    BindItemsDataSource();
}

protected void rItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        bool edit = e.Item.ItemIndex == m_editIndex;
        HtmlGenericControl tbody = e.Item.FindControl("itemRows") as HtmlGenericControl;
        tbody.Visible = !edit;
        tbody = e.Item.FindControl("editItemRows") as HtmlGenericControl;
        tbody.Visible = edit;

        if (edit)
        {
            PopulateEditableFieldValues(e.Item);
        }
    }
}
```