# Is there an ASP.Net equivalent to Windows Forms's DataGridView?

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

Yesterday, I asked this question: [Creating ASP.Net DataBound control that renders table with multiple tbodies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417329/creating-asp-net-databound-control-that-renders-table-with-multiple-tbodies).

#### Summary of original question:

> I need to make a data-bound table for which every data item/row has its own`<tbody>`, and an arbitrary number of `<tr>`-rows within.
>
> `<asp:DataList>`, my original solution, automatically generates a `<span>`, `<li>`, or `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` for each data item depending on its `RepeatLayout` property value.  So, I can't use that without some ugly jquery hacks.
>
> My understanding is that `<asp:DataGrid>` allows you to specify columns and cell templates, but not row templates themselves; that's even less versatile for my needs.
>
> I ended up using an `<asp:Repeater>` to solve my problem, but it doesn't automatically come with edit functionality (which I did myself), nor paging/sorting functionality (which I need to do next).

The first comment on my last question said I needed to google `DataGridView`.  At the time I assumed he meant `<asp:DataGrid>`, but looking again, I realized he didn't.  `DataGridView` appears to be just a Windows Forms control, but from a cursory glance, it appears to be something worth looking into.

Is there an ASP.Net equivalent of `DataGridView` that allows complete control over the container- and item-templates?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [`GridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It has sorting, editing and paging capabilities. It also has `ItemTemplates` where you can add any kind of controls/HTML or `UserControls` which contain any kind of controls/HTML.

Comment: My understanding is that `GridView` only allows you to template cells, not entire rows.  Am I wrong about that?  (I'll update the original question to summarize the link, so people don't have to click it.)

Comment: You are right. It has tabular layout. But it is the ASP.NET version of the DataGridView.